# Obfuscation .Net Dll

Tags: c#, obfuscation

How can we obfuscate .Net dll (MVC web application)?

As, I am trying to obfuscate MVC website dll using Dotfuscator, when I run application using obfuscated dll it dont work properly, show website HTML content or website structure.

Comment: You have to be careful obfuscating MVC.  Certain method and class names must not be renamed to things like `A` and  `A.A1()`, random names such tools create by default

Answer (score 1):

Why would you? Web application binaries reside on the server, and with sane configuration settings they're unretrievable through HTTP requests. If this is not the case, you'd best spend your time to configure your web server instead.

As to why you can't really obfuscate MVC code, the architecture they went with uses a lot of reflection, like *a lot*. And because functions aren't actually called from code, the obfuscators won't know to update the "caller" side through reflection and it'll just crash.

Comment: Maybe he has to install on client's hardware and does not want to hand in binaries which can be easily reverse engineered? Or wants to obfuscate some encryption keys in code? Reasons are plenty.

Comment: And all wrong. If your product is worth the money it'll be bought. If not nobody will care enough to reverse engineer it. Spend your time making something good instead of this.

Comment: By using reverse engineering tool we can easily extract code from binaries (dll). that cause insecure for application because Logic can be easily readable from your code.

Comment: Security through obscurity is a running joke through circles who actually write secure applications. If that's what you need to be secure (as @MihaiCaracostea likes too, apparently), prepare your checkbook for multi-million dollar lawsuits like the whole Ashley-Maddison debacle in recent news. And again I'll point out that it's a web application, if people reverse engineer your DLLs from that, whoever sets up your web servers should absolutely be fired for criminal incompetence. People write secure PHP applications with absolutely no compilation or obfuscation involved.

Comment: @TalhaAbdulMuqsit A agree with Blindy. Server-side software gains security though the data center in which it is deployed.  How can an end-user run a decompiler through server-side binaries.  There are discussions right here on SO detailing how obfuscators have already been broken and their usefulness today quite limited

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your mvc app is blowing up is that by default dotfuscator uses a type of obfuscation where it renames classes, methods and pretty much everything thing else that gets a name.  It's probably more "secure" and all but renaming obfuscation kills anything that uses reflection.

The good news is that you can configure dofuscator to use another approach called control flow obfuscation.  When you enable that, disable the renaming obfuscation and you should be ok.

If this wasnt enough info and you think im on the right track for you, reply to me and i can post a dotfuscator config example in the morning. (It's 1:30 am where i am)